# Router can ping external IP, PC going thru same router can't

Tags: cisco, routing

I have a lab setup with 3 routers and 3 switches, but for simplicity for this issue, I turned on only 1 router and 1 switch and ran this test with the same results so I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with my ip route statements.

```
PC >> Cisco Router >> Cisco switch >> Home Router
```

> Router
>
> FE0/0 192.168.1.15 /24
>
> FE0/1 192.168.10.1 /24
>
> ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1

---

> Switch (default vlan1 only)
>
> 192.168.1.20 /24
>
> ip default-gateway 192.168.1.1

The default-gateway is my live/home router that I access the internet.

The problem is: The router (192.168.1.15) can ping outside addresses, but even if I plug my PC directly into the routers FE0/1 port (192.168.10.1), the router will not forward anything to the outside world from my PC. If the router can get out, why can't my PC? The PC has no problem pinging the FE0/0 interface.

> PC
>
> IP 192.168.10.51 /24
>
> Gateway 192.168.10.1
>
> DNS 192.168.1.1

Router - show ip route...

> Gateway of last resort is 192.168.1.1 to network 0.0.0.0
>
> S*    0.0.0.0/0 [1/0] via 192.168.1.1
>
> 192.168.1.0/24 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
>
> C        192.168.1.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
>
> L        192.168.1.15/32 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: Does your home router (configurations for consumer-grade devices are off topic) have a route to 192.168.10.0/24? It needs a route to know where to send traffic destined for that route, else it will send it out the default route (WAN).

Comment: Oh wow. I was getting NAT and routing mixed up in my head. I know the difference, but for some reason couldn't get it straight in my head. I was thinking that the Cisco router was doing a type of 'address translation'. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your home router needs a route to the `192.168.10.0/24` route. It needs a route to know where to send traffic destined for that route, else it will send it out the default route (WAN).

Comment: Thank again Ron. For others that run into this issue... I added NAT to my Cisco router since my home router doesn't support this. It's working fine, I used this site... http://www.firewall.cx/cisco-technical-knowledgebase/cisco-routers/260-cisco-router-nat-overload.html